# Segmentation fault using group add

Tags: debian, installation, debian-squeeze, aptitude, tftp

Today I tried to install a tftp server to setup a PXE server on a virtual machine (powered by VMware ESX 4) for our network to ease server installation. The base installation (Debian 7.5.0 x64) worked flawless but when I hit the commands to install tftpd-hpa with aptitude the installer ran into an error.

```
root@bsl-lab-pxe:~# aptitude install tftpd-hpa
The following packages will be upgraded: 
  tftpd-hpa 
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/47.6 kB of archives. After unpacking 110 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Reading changelogs... Done               
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 28425 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace tftpd-hpa 5.0-18 (using .../tftpd-hpa_5.2-4_amd64.deb) ...
[ ok ] Stopping HPA's tftpd: in.tftpd.
Unpacking replacement tftpd-hpa ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up tftpd-hpa (5.2-4) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa ...
adduser: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 106 tftp' exited from signal 11. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing tftpd-hpa (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tftpd-hpa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up tftpd-hpa (5.2-4) ...
adduser: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 106 tftp' exited from signal 11. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing tftpd-hpa (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tftpd-hpa
```

I tried to reconfigure the package and also to remove it completely (using purge option) and reinstall from scratch but both options didn't work. Since the two most obvious troubleshooting methods didn't work I took a close look at the actual output. The installer calls user add which executes groupadd in order to create the group "tftp" but that ends in an error.

```
    /usr/sbin/groupadd -g 106 tftp' exited from signal 11. Exiting.
```

I was wondering what happens if I directly execute that program so I went on and entered the follow line on the CLI:

```
    groupadd -g 106 tftp
    Segmentation fault
```

As the error message wasn't really helpful I looked into syslog and dmesg for more information.

dmesg:

```
        root@bsl-lab-pxe:~# dmesg | tail -n20
[    6.519734] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    6.519737] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    6.519738] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    6.519739] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    6.604399] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    6.638642] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    6.647444] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
[  372.174406] groupadd[2667]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff93b0cc98 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[  373.850102] groupadd[2690]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffaa5f9558 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[  684.850877] groupadd[2976]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff65247df8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[  686.028112] groupadd[2999]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffa1192cd8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[  836.532472] groupadd[3182]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffd4150458 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[  909.654930] groupadd[3284]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffa1aae538 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[  910.938959] groupadd[3305]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff710d92b8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[  989.342821] groupadd[3700]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff0a5070c8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[  990.920531] groupadd[3721]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff22c4e108 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[ 1000.975599] groupadd[3757]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff3e6483f8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[ 1002.145736] groupadd[3778]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffab3d0dc8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[ 1246.341294] groupadd[3810]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff73f17558 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
[ 1251.001165] groupadd[3811]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007ffff4573668 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
```

syslog:

```
root@bsl-lab-pxe:~# cat /var/log/syslog | tail -n20
Jun  2 19:11:07 bsl-lab-pxe acpid: starting up with netlink and the input layer
Jun  2 19:11:07 bsl-lab-pxe acpid: 1 rule loaded
Jun  2 19:11:07 bsl-lab-pxe acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
Jun  2 19:11:07 bsl-lab-pxe /usr/sbin/cron[2110]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jun  2 19:11:07 bsl-lab-pxe /usr/sbin/cron[2111]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Jun  2 19:11:07 bsl-lab-pxe /usr/sbin/cron[2111]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jun  2 19:11:08 bsl-lab-pxe mpt-statusd: detected non-optimal RAID status
Jun  2 19:17:01 bsl-lab-pxe /USR/SBIN/CRON[2631]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun  2 19:17:12 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [  372.174406] groupadd[2667]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff93b0cc98 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:17:14 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [  373.850102] groupadd[2690]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffaa5f9558 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:21:09 bsl-lab-pxe mpt-statusd: detected non-optimal RAID status
Jun  2 19:22:25 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [  684.850877] groupadd[2976]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff65247df8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:22:27 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [  686.028112] groupadd[2999]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffa1192cd8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:24:57 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [  836.532472] groupadd[3182]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffd4150458 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:26:11 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [  909.654930] groupadd[3284]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffa1aae538 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:26:12 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [  910.938959] groupadd[3305]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff710d92b8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:27:30 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [  989.342821] groupadd[3700]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff0a5070c8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:27:32 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [  990.920531] groupadd[3721]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff22c4e108 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:27:42 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [ 1000.975599] groupadd[3757]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff3e6483f8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
Jun  2 19:27:43 bsl-lab-pxe kernel: [ 1002.145736] groupadd[3778]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffab3d0dc8 error 14 in groupadd[400000+c000]
```

I don't know how to proceed and I'd like to avoid using back-ports if possible, but of ours I'll do that if I have to.
Has anybody experienced a similar issue bevor or does someone have an advise where I could look for additional error message/troubleshooting steps?

Alls tipps, links, questions I might have missed (sorry if so) are very welcome.
Thanks for taking the time and your effort.

Best regards

Comment: Run `grpck` on the machine, then try it again.

Comment: Thanks for your hint Nathan. I ran the command on the server but it didn't produce any output, so I assumed that the group file must be allright. Also I checked syslog and dmesg again and there were no new entries that would indicate an error (regarding grpck).

Comment: May want to try just reinstalling Linux again ...it's quite possible something went amiss.

Comment: what about "apt-get install tftpd-hpa" is it giving you the same error?

Comment: Do other commands work?  you could try to prepend `strace` (`strace groupadd`...) to see which system call is problematic.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs, I tried the instructions you gave me but in the end I reinstalled the OS and was successful with the installation of tftpd-hpa. I guess there must have been something gone wrong during the upgrade from squeeze to wheezy. Rgds